# Prove that E is open

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis

Let E=$\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2  : x^2 +y^2 > 1\}$ Prove that E is open.

So far I have $\vec p \in E $.

Let $\vec x \in B_r(\vec p)$

$r=\Vert\vec p\Vert-1 >0$

$\Vert\vec x -\vec p\Vert <r=\Vert\vec p\Vert-1 $

Comment: On the way : Once you take $r = \|p\| - 1$, then all you need to do is prove that if $\|x - p\| \leq r$ then $\|x\| > 1$. Can you see this?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $(x,y) \mapsto x^2 + y^2$ is continuous.
$E = f^{-1}(1,\infty)$.
$(1,\infty)$ is an open set.
Inverse images of an open set by a continuous function are open.